# How to do zero damage Terraria?

Tags: terraria

So I'm making a grinder that needs me to continually hit enemies (And record it as my hit, so no lava) and it would be very helpful if there was a way to do zero damage

P.S. though it would be helpful if it could be performed afk, manual would be alright.

Comment: Why? What's the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible. Per [the wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Damage#Calculations), the minimum amount of damage you can do to enemies is 1.

You can see this for yourself by fighting a Dungeon Guardian. They have 9999 defense, which means they reduce incoming damage by ~5000. Even the strongest weapons in the game don't do that much damage, which means that theoretically it cannot be damaged at all. However, every time it gets hit, it still takes 1 damage, which makes it killable (though very, very tanky).

Comment: Thanks though so you know of a way to do 1 damage afk while having the damage be credited to the player, preferably fast?

Comment: @brododragon I assume you're trying to do a money farm with the Lucky Coin? If that's the case, the most popular method of grinding money is to set up a farm and use the slime staff as the damage source. The slime summon attacks very fast but deals very little damage (in hardmode it's pretty much always 1 damage, especially if you reforge it with a weak prefix). Add a set of Tiki Armor to let you summon more of them at once and you've got a pretty decent setup.

Comment: Ok nice I got a couple slime staffs lying around